# Difference between non-graphic characters and non-printable characters

Tags: bash, ls, control-characters

**My system:**

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

`man ls` describes `-b` as follows:

```
   -b, --escape
          print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters
```

The [Wikipedia page for "control character"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) states:

> a control character or non-printing character (NPC) is a code point
> in a character set that does not represent a written character or
> symbol. All other characters are mainly graphic characters, also known
> as printing characters (or printable characters), except perhaps for
> "space" characters.

This is ambiguous.

What authoritative resource explains what nongraphic characters are, and how this term may differ from non-printing characters?

Comment: look at the first 32 characters at https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: The Awk documentation is usually both readable and reliable: see `https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions`. However, one significant issue is that the definitions may depend on the current Locale settings. Multi-byte characters (e.g. UTF-8) are a whole new game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Bash script tabulates the character classes associated with each character in the ASCII set (according to GNU/awk definitions).

```
#! /bin/bash --

Awk='
BEGIN {
    Ctl1 = "SOH STX ETX EOT ENQ ACK BEL BS HT LF VT FF CR SO SI ";
    Ctl2 = "DC1 DC2 DC3 DC4 NAK SYN ETB CAN EM SUB ESC FS GS RS US SPACE";
    split (Ctl1 Ctl2, Ctl); Ctl[0] = "NUL"; Ctl[127] = "DEL";
    C = "cntrl print graph space blank punct alnum alpha digit lower upper xdigit";
    split (C, Class); 
}
function Char (n, ch, Local, j) {

    printf ("0x%.2X  %5s", n, (n <= 32 || n == 127) ? Ctl[n] : ch);
    for (j = 1; j in Class; ++j) 
        if (ch ~ "[[:" Class[j] ":]]") printf ("  :%s:", Class[j]);
    printf ("\n");
}
{ for (j = 0; j < 128; j++) Char( j, sprintf ("%c", j)); }
'
    echo | awk -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" )
```

Comment: ASCII represents a tiny fraction of all possible characters. See [Command to retrieve the list of characters in a given character class in the current locale](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128192) to extend it outside of ASCII.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  I read (scanned anyway) that, right down to "See 24 more comments". Suddenly, I am nostalgic for my ICL 1901A 6-bit character set - no direct lowercase. We could deal with ASCII peripherals (paper-tape, printers, OCR readers, VDUs): Alpha and Beta shift codes for upper and lower case, Delta for control characters.

Answer (score 1):

The *graphic characters* would be the one for which the [`isgraph()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/isgraph.html)/[`iswgraph()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/iswgraph.html) standard functions return true or the ones matched by the `[[:graph:]]` regular expressions, that is the ones in the `graph` character class in the locale.

Per [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01), the `print` class must be a superset of `graph` and be disjunct from `cntrl` and `graph` must be a superset of `upper`, `lower`, `alpha`, `digit`, `xdigit`, and `punct` and must not include the space (U+0020) character (with no mention of other whitespace characters).

The idea being that the *graphic* characters would be the ones for which ink would be used to draw them, while *printable* would be the non-control ones.

In practice, on GNU systems (such as Ubuntu) at least `print` is `graph` plus the non-control characters from the `space` class. Here with glibc 2.35 (as used on Ubuntu 22.04) and in UTF-8 locales, that includes:

```
U+0020 SPACE
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+2000 EN QUAD
U+2001 EM QUAD
U+2002 EN SPACE
U+2003 EM SPACE
U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+2009 THIN SPACE
U+200A HAIR SPACE
U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

While the `space` class has:

```
U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
U+000A LINE FEED
U+000B LINE TABULATION
U+000C FORM FEED
U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
U+0020 SPACE
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+2000 EN QUAD
U+2001 EM QUAD
U+2002 EN SPACE
U+2003 EM SPACE
U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+2009 THIN SPACE
U+200A HAIR SPACE
U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```